# iframe "File not found" error

Tags: android, html, iframe, webview

I don't know much about html but there is a small issue and I am unable to find its solution.
This is the iframe that I want to display on static html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <iframe style="width:120px;height:240px; padding-right:50px; padding-bottom:50px" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&OneJS=1&Operation=GetAdHtml&MarketPlace=US&source=ac&ref=qf_sp_asin_til&ad_type=product_link&tracking_id=qstore51214-20&marketplace=amazon&region=US&placement=0553496670&asins=0553496670&linkId=4f9912a00b832e2f8bcb5a9b187511cf&show_border=true&link_opens_in_new_window=true&price_color=333333&title_color=0066c0&bg_color=ffffff">
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I add this to html and try to open html page, I get the error: 
"File not found".
But when I add this iframe to any [live html editor](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default) it work perfectly and show the link.

Actually I want to display this iframe in Webview in my Andriod application.

My android code is:

```
mWebViewTopSeller = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewTopSeller);
mWebViewTopSeller.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
mWebViewTopSeller.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
mWebViewTopSeller.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebViewTopSeller.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/TopSeller.html");
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: If this is an HTML issue and the only Android part is you want to display it on Android, remove the Android tag. This is web stuff, not Android

Comment: I mentioned that I want to show this in Android webview that's why I added android tag as well.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I have updated the exact html code. Please check now

Comment: But my internet connection is working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152390/discussion-between-ghulam-rasool-and-yvette-colomb).

Comment: Android code is added as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When embedding this iframe, it returns an error:

`SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by https://ws-na...`

So it may have something to do with the browser's mixed-content/same-origin policy.

Comment: Actually it is the link created by amazon. I wonder if its not showing in html page, then why its showing in html live editor?

Comment: Turns out that this error occured because of my AdBlocker, so forget the answer above. :\

For your problem, make sure that the file *TopSeller.html* is in the `src/main/assets/` folder (file names are case-sensitive).

Comment: No, its not the issue of adBlocker. I just attached https:// before starting link and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Possible src values are an absolute URL that points to another web site (like src="http://www.example.com/default.htm")
or an relative URL that points to a file within a web site (like src="default.htm" I think your src path is wrong.

Comment: If this is the case, then why its working in live html editor